# how to continue any tag inline after <h5> tag

Tags: asp.net, html, css, html-table

First See the image given below.

[image]

code here:

```
    <h5>
        Login!</h5>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="_userName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="_password" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="_login" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="_login_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <asp:Label ID="_wrongDetails" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want username immediately after login text.
I have tried position:inline. but it's not working. or can anyone help me to get started in css stuff. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Advice: screenshot, mark with paint what's wrong :)

Comment: If I get you right, you want to have "Login! User Name: ..."?

Comment: Without seeing it, I'd say your table is what is causing the break between 'Login!' and 'User Name'.

Comment: You could fix this with css hackery, but the best solution would be to change your HTML. Tables are not meant for this purpose. Divs or unordered lists would be more semantic, and easier to style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set display:inline style in both h5 tag and table tag also. Then it will not cause both tag to break a line and hence display it in a single line.

fix it:

```
    <h5 style="display:inline">
    Login!</h5>
<table style="display:inline">
..
..
```

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `<h5>` to be `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

That would cause it not to break the line.

You may want to use a `<form>` for the login **form** instead of a `<table>`.